# ASRock B450M Pro 4 wont see either SSD

Tags: ssd, motherboard, uefi

first time PC builder here. As the title states, I have a ASRock B450M Pro4 mobo with 1 Samsung 970 EVO Plus NVME M.2 stick in the M2 slot and 1 ADATA SU800 M.2 2280 in the Ultra M2 slot.

I've checked and both are supposedly supported… and I have nothing plugged into the SATA Port 3.

Neither show up in the UEFI. Is there something I need to enable in UEFI for them to be seen?

I have seen many posts from people regarding this… but not much in terms of resolution. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

thanks!
A

Comment: Looks like you've done a lot of the leg work already. What did ASRock say when you called them regarding the issue? Is your BIOS/UEFI up-to-date?

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't take calls. I filed a support ticket with them. I believe the BIOS/UEFI is current, 3.30. I am going to re-check that though. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you checked this page? https://www.asrock.com/general/about.asp?cat=Contact